# Multi-language Auth Dialog on Facebook apps

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a facebook app on a canvas/page tab.

There's some way to show the text in the Auth Dialog page in the user language? I'm referring to the *subtitle* and *summary* customization.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Translate your app" button:

[image]